# Kotlin Handler class: How to stop a thread - from inside of run() - when a condition is met?

Tags: android, function, loops, kotlin, android-handler

I am currently learning how to develop android applications. For my first app, I wanted to build a simple clicker with a primitive combat sistem.

In my code, I have created a *Handler instance* and a *Runnable object*. Inside of this "delayed loop" the enemy attacks the player instance every 3 seconds, dealing damage. Inside the loop I also test when the player's hp is *less or equals 0*; when the condition is met I want to *stop the runnable object*.

How do i do this? I tried calling a function `stopCombat()` which contains `Handler.removeCallbacks`, but i can't call a function before declaration. I tried putting `.removeCallbacks(this)` inside `run()`, but it also doesn't work.

```
val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    fun playerDied() {
        ongoingFight = false
        combatLog.append("${myPlayer.name} has been defeated!\n")
        myPlayer.currentHitPoints = myPlayer.maxHitPoints / 2
        myPlayer.gold = 0
        gold.text = "${myPlayer.gold} gold"
    }


    val performTask = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            val enemyHit = enemyAttack(myPlayer, myEnemy)
            // Call a function to stop this thread if the condition is met:
            if (myPlayer.takeDamage(enemyHit)) { //myPlayer.takeDamage returns true if hp <= 0
                playerDied()
                stopCombat() // called before declaration
                mainHandler.removeCallbacks(this) // tried, doesn't work
            }
            playerHP.text = "${myPlayer.currentHitPoints} / ${myPlayer.maxHitPoints}"
            combatLog.append("${myEnemy.name} deals $enemyHit damage!\n")
            mainHandler.postDelayed(this, 3000)
        }
    }

    fun stopCombat(){
        mainHandler.removeCallbacks(performTask)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a boolean to determine if you’re going to post the runnable again

```
override fun run() {
    val enemyHit = enemyAttack(myPlayer, myEnemy)
    val died = myPlayer.takeDamage(enemyHit)) 
    if (died) 
        playerDied()
   playerHP.text = "${myPlayer.currentHitPoints} / ${myPlayer.maxHitPoints}"
            combatLog.append("${myEnemy.name} deals $enemyHit damage!\n")
    if (!died)
        mainHandler.postDelayed(this, 3000)
}
```

Sorry for formatting—on my phone.

Comment: Wow, this was so elegant! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you are using kotlin. I think you can use coroutines. It's more concise and lightweight. [Cancellation and Timeouts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html)

If you still want to use thread. Try the following code.

```
    val executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    val runnables = Runnable {

    }
    val task = executorService.submit(runnables)
    task.cancel(true)
```

Comment: This would cause the loop to run on a separate thread from the rest of the game and force you to make all the shared properties volatile and the classes thread safe.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I will dig into coroutines this weekend